# how to give custom domain name of windows azure hosted site

Tags: azure, dns

I am new on Windows Azure. I have a free trial account of Windows Azure. I have created a web application in asp.net and have published it on Windows Azure. The URL looks like it below.

http://ssoimplenentation.azurewebsites.net/

It is possible to give custom domain name of Windows Azure hosted site with free trial account? 
OR
How to give custom domain name of Windows Azure hosted site with free trial account?

Answer (score 3):

Custom domains are do supported by Windows Azure Websites. However, you have to have your website in at least `Shared` or `Reserved` website mode. `Free` mode does not allow to have custom domains. I think the same applies to free trial account as `Shared` and `Reserved` website mode are not free of charge.

[image: Windows Azure Mode]

If you have your website in one of the mentioned modes, you configure your custom domains in `Configure` tab, `domain names` section. As mentioned above, in `Free` mode that section will be disabled.

[image: Windows Azure Custom Domains]

Please bear in mind that you will have to **configure your DNS first**, before adding custom mode to Azure configuration. When you add new domain name to Azure, DNS servers are checked to find out if the domain name points to Azure. If that condition is not met, you will get an error message and Azure will not accept that domain name.

I hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/. Please note that at this time the option to map a custom domain name to an azure website is only available when the website is running under shared or reserved mode.